# How do I make Handsontable available to my Laravel Blade component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, components, laravel-blade, handsontable

I'm making a table editor in Laravel using a Blade component. I want to use Handsontable so I've installed it via NPM and added the import statements to app.js and then run Laravel Mix to build the output.

How do I then access this from the script tag in my Component file? I tried following the installation guide here: https://handsontable.com/docs/installation/#overview but I get an error in the javascript console that Handsontable is undefined. How can I make it defined and/or in scope?

Any help appreciated!